# Unable to connect to azure from a specific server

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have an Azure service bus queue which can't connect to my queue. On my pc it works fine, On our dev server it also works fine. We have deployed it on our test box and We are getting this error when trying to receive messages from the queue:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException:  Could
>   not connect to net.tcp://jeportal.servicebus.windows.net:9354/.  The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:14.9062482. TCP
>   error code 10060:  A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time,  or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   168.62.48.238:9354.   ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://jeportal.servicebus.windows.net:9354/.   The connection
>   attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:14.9062482. TCP error code
>   10060:   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time,   or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   168.62.48.238:9354.    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond 
>     168.62.48.238:9354

We have disabled the firewall and it still doesn't work, any suggestions on troubleshooting ?

Comment: Can you resolve the destination name correctly and tracert from your test server to the destination?

Comment: I just   did it on my PC which has access to but the tracert didn't workalso UPDATE: we are able to query the QueueDescription.

Comment: tracert jeportal.servicebus.windows.net

Tracing route to ns-sb2-prod-bl2-001.cloudapp.net [168.62.48.238]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.108.129
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: So you can definitely access the Queue machine from the test machine, but you can't access the Queue data?

Comment: yes that is correct glenatron

Answer (score 1):

If this is related to firewall setting that you may want to try to set the connectivity mode to Http. More details at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitysettings.mode.aspx
and: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the timeouts on your bindings to 1 minute and add your server application as an exception in Windows Firewall manually.

Comment: Have you tried using any other binding wsHttpBinding or BasicHttpBinding to see if you can communicate with the server at all?

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being a simple issue of ou network firewall being restricted. We had told our SA's to open the ports up for 9354 goinging to the sb. They said they did open them... but they didn't. I walked throght it with them and we discovered it wasn't open